# Thread-safe comparison of an enum value in Java

Tags: java, enums, thread-safety, synchronized

This is my current code. I want to understand if I need to wrap `isObjectActive()` in a the synchronized block if `getState()` is already synchronized ?

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
@GuardedBy("lock")
private EventTypes state;

@GuardedBy("lock")
public void setState(final EventTypes state) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}

@GuardedBy("lock")
@VisibleForTesting
public EventTypes getState() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        return state;
    }
}

@GuardedBy("lock")
public boolean isObjectActive() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        return getState() == EventTypes.ACTIVE;
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do. Even with `getState()` being synchronized without that other synchronized block the returned state might have changed already when the check is performed. However, that actually might happen right before or after that check so would it really be an issue if `getState()` returned a state that has been changed right after that call?

Comment: @Thomas, You are trying to answer a different question--a question about code, which the OP hasn't shown, that calls the functions above. _That_ code _might_ need additional synchronization, but the `synchronized` block in `isObjectActive()` confers no advantage whatsoever.

Comment: In your case (if it would be fine if the result isObjectActive might be an old state), then consider removing the lock and use a `volatile` state field.

Comment: @SolomonSlow that's what I was trying to convey:be aware that the synchronized `isObjectActive()` doesn't add any benefit so think about what the scope of synchronization should be and work on that part.

Comment: @Thomas, there's two distinct issues, and your comments seem to conflate them. The first issue is whether or not the synchronization in `isObjectActive()` _adds_ any benefit given that `getState()` already is synchronized. The answer to that question is simple. It does not. The second issue is whether the `synchronized` blocks in `setState()` and `getState()` provide the protection that the OP _thinks_ they provide. That's harder to answer because we have no example of code that calls those methods. We can only speculate, and mention the obvious mistake that the OP _might_ be making.

Comment: @SolomonSlow you're right. My intention was to point attention to the more important second question the answer to which would make the first question obsolete :) - I wanted to address the xy-problem I feel here without actually asking whether it actually is one. My bad.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion guys. The purpose of my question was to understand if there's any benefit of the synchronization in the `inObjectActive()` method and the discussion answers my question. I am in the process of refactoring some legacy code and wanted to understand this specific implementation related question. But I am still in the process of designing the change, which means I haven't pushed this and am still trying to understand how `state` is actually being used. I will keep in mind the second issue you guys pointed out before finalizing my strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Do] I need to wrap isObjectActive() in a the synchronized block...?

No.

Synchronization isn't for *methods*, it's for data. In the example shown above, you can remove the `synchronized` block from `isObjectActive()`, because that function does not directly access the `state` variable, and the only other function that it calls *does* use synchronization when accessing `state`.

@Thomas made a good point though in the comment that he left on your question: You probably should think about what the result of an `isObjectActive()` call means if the action of some other thread can change the state of the object before the caller gets a chance to act on the result:

```
MyType mt = ...;

if (mt.isObjectActive()) {
    // This is broken because there's no guarantee that mt still will be "active"
    // by the time doSomething...() gets called.
    //
    doSomethingThatOnlyMakesSenseWhen_mt_IsActive(...);
}
```